# Return same object from Java8 lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have the following code:

```
@Test
public void testAverageFromArray() {
    final Double[] dbls = { 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 };
    final double av = Stream.of(dbls).mapToDouble(d -> d).average().getAsDouble();
    assertEquals(1.3, av, 0);
}
```

Question:
Is it possible to replace the **d -> d** lambda with some other syntax?  It seems needless.

*I wasnt sure about the title of this question - please edit if its off the mark.

thanks

Comment: I suppose this is just an example but it seems strange to have `Double[]` in the first place. If you could obtain the same data as a `double[]` instead, you could use `DoubleStream.of(double...)` to build your stream (or `Arrays.stream(double[])`).

Comment: The lambda `d -> d` is really shorthand for `d -> (double) d`, which is an unboxing conversion.  It looks like an identity conversion because `javac` implicitly inserts boxing conversions for you.  You could also use `Double::doubleValue` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda `d -> d` is not needless. What happens is that you need to provide a function `T -> double`. In fact `d -> d` is a function `Double -> double` because the unboxing is done automatically (since Java 5).

You could always replace it with a method reference `.mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)` to make it clear that it unboxes the double value for the Double instance you're processing.

Comment: This is what I thought, but wasn't sure if there was an alternative syntax which performed the same function.  Its good to confirm that this is the best way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are converting a `Stream<Double>` to a `DoubleStream`. The latter has the convenience method `average()` which `Stream` can’t offer as it’s a generic class that can be used with arbitrary types.

Thus, for the conversion of the arbitrary type `T` of a `Stream<T>` to the `double` element type of a `DoubleStream`, the conversion function is needed, even if it is as simple as `d -> d`, when utilizing the fact that you and the compiler, unlike the stream implementation, know that the element type is `Double` which can get implicitly unboxed.

Note that when the conversion function is required anyway, the method `DoubleStream.average()` stops being that convenient and you could also use:

```
final double av = Stream.of(dbls).collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(d -> d));
```

using the `import static` feature, it becomes:

```
final double av = Stream.of(dbls).collect(averagingDouble(d -> d));
```

Just for completeness, you could even do it without a `d -> d` function using

```
final double av = Stream.of(dbls).collect(DoubleSummaryStatistics::new,
        DoubleSummaryStatistics::accept, DoubleSummaryStatistics::combine)
    .getAverage();
```

but, of course, this doesn’t add to readability nor brevity. It’s the explicit form of what the `summarizingDouble(…)` collector does, but in this form we can get rid of the `mapper` function.